# Unable to pipe python output to program

Tags: python, linux

I want to pipe stdout from python to another program, but I am faceing a problem where my stdout is not piped.

I have it shortened down to a simple sample:

```
import time

while True:
    print("Hello!")
    time.sleep(1)
```

I check it with cat like so:

```
./my_python_script.py | cat
```

And then I get nothing at all.

Strange thing is that it works just fine if i remove the sleep command. However, I do not want to pipe the output that fast, so I would really like to sleep for a second.

I checked with the corresponding bash script:

```
while true; do
    echo "Hello!"
    sleep 1
done
```

And that works like a charm too. So any idea as to why the python script does not pipe the output as expected? Thanks!

Comment: By default, pipes only send data when their buffer fills up (usually 8K).  Your example would have worked eventually, if you had waited long enough.  Your non-sleep example worked because it filled up the buffer immediately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to flush the stdout:

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    print("Hello!")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I had a feeling it had to do with buffer not filling up fast enough